# web page usability

Tags: java, html, standards, usability

Can low level metrics (such as word count) measure over web interface elements cover web page and site usability?

Comment: Word count is easy to collect.  What's a "web interface element"?  And what's "usability"?  How do you score this "usability"?  Is it on a scale from 1 to 10?

Comment: word count is just example..web page elements are such as link, image,words,et., usability means the ability of a user to successfully use the web pages to perform tasks.

Comment: @naw naw: "ability of a user to successfully use the web pages"?  How do you measure this?  If you're going to use metrics, there must be some measurement of usability.  What is this measurement?  Which one are you planning to use?

Comment: my proposed metrics are based on web sites usability guidelines and extend prior research...i can propose low level measurement..i am going create automated computation tool to measure ..overall reading complexity within each web page including (words, links , bulleted list and so on )is one of the metrics i used to measure..when i measure reading complexity for over all page..i got two different values..under threshold and over threshold.

Comment: .some metrics i would like to measure is based on usability guidelines and extracted from the characteristics of web usability..I need help..but i think that .. i have a lack of background knowledge and also.. lack of communication skill.. thank you

Comment: @naw naw: If you have all that, what are you asking?  You already have everything you need.

Comment: I'm afraid that my trend is impossible or not...I have some proposed metrics..these can be extracted by manually..but i don't sure extracted by automated tool...how do you think sir..give me any suggestion..i appreciate your experiences..I am just a student..

Comment: let me sign out sir.. want to see u again to discuss with you

Answer (score 1):

The thing about usability is that no matter how much researchers and engineers try to quantify usability, it can't be accurately measured as a whole.  For example, let's say that Google, with it's sub-500 words and one sprited-image is a very "useable" site.  Now, let's do a page with one image (black on black writing) on a black screen....let's add a javascript blink to it.  The second could have exactly the same amount of elements and the same amount of Javascript as your standard, but one is clearly better.  By the same token, you could use word count as a measure, but what happens when you hit a site that's all flash and has no forward-facing text to speak of.  It might be a beautiful site (I use that loosely because I'm not a fan of Flash) but by your test's measures, it's a complete failure.

Then you get into concepts like location precedence, separating content in images vs content in text (not all text is actually text on a site), color palettes, expected vs actual functionality, accessibility, compatibility with various browsers and technologies, etc.

There's a reason that testers are paid to interact with enterprise-level sites, graphic designers are paid to make layouts, and UI Engineers (like me) are paid to figure out how to effectively make the interface function effectively with the user...it's because there isn't a way to replace us (yet).

Never mind the fact that the "experts" still haven't figured out exactly what to test for.  For every Jakob Nielson finding, there's several others that contradict his findings.  Remember, while there's an accepted standard out there (W3c) the browser family with the biggest market share still doesn't entirely accept it, meaning that w3c isn't necessarily a 100% valid singular testing standard (as much as that hurt to write....)

Of course, you could [just try the HiPPO](http://www.askahippo.com/).  I hear it has a very good API and is always right.

Comment: I'm a fan of this response.  (-Sr. UI Engineer working for large gov't agency trying to maintain UI sanity one day at a time...)